# Middle vertical align for <a> in <li> menu

Tags: html, css

I need to vertically align in middle labels of menu. Allso if client will change the value of label and it will break in two lines, it'll stays in middle. As i know vertical-align: middle works for table cells, but I need to generate menu from `<li>` elements. See example code below.

html

```
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">qwe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">asd</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">zxcvbnm asdfgh</a></li>
  </ul>
```

css

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 1px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: tomato;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
a {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And working prototype at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/awihoy/1/edit)

Comment: forget to del vertical-align: middle; - ofcaurse they don't work

Comment: See http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi now give to li `display:table-cell` and **remove** `float:left`

as like this

```
    li {
     display:table-cell;
       vertical-align: middle;
float:left; // remove this line  
    }
```

***[Demo](http://jsbin.com/awihoy/4/edit)***

Answer (score 0):

Just add `line-height:60px` to your `a` tag and it works.

**[See Demo](http://jsbin.com/awihoy/7/edit)**

Comment: it will break the menu element if there is two line of text.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline-block` for `<a>` elements.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  float:left;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 1px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: tomato;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

Example fiddle : http://jsbin.com/ohazot/1/edit